# The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game using Cocos2d-x to Android and iPhone. At the beggining, I had a lot of problems to start using this library, so, in this question, I want to collect all basic, medium and expert tutorials because there are a lot of info questions doing the same mistakes. When I [Started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979795/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-to-start-programming-using-cocos2d-x), I had to look a lot in many sites using my friend Google. Hope this helps people start now. **All in c++**.

**Beginners**

- Official wiki [links](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki)
- How to start in multi-platform [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) The best one. Amazing, XCODE (MAC) and ECLIPSE (LINUX) tutorial.
- A simple guide to [Start](http://developer.bada.com/library/BalloonRide)
- Another multi-platform [Guide](http://gameit.ro/2012/01/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project-updated/)
- Awesome guide to start programming on [Eclipse + Android](http://blog.plicatibu.com/developing-with-cocos2d-x-for-android-on-linux/) and [DEBUG](http://blog.plicatibu.com/how-to-debug-cocos2d-x-and-java-code-using-eclipse/), thanks to [Marcio Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88211/marcio-andrey-oliveira)
- Another [way](http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/26000816688/integrate-cocos2d-x-c-into-an-android-application) to integrate cocos2d-x on Android
- Social Example, Facebook + email + Twitter on iOS and Android [HERE](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12492)

**Medium**

- Scrolling scenes. Using CCParallaxNode. [Space game example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11338/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-space-game)
- InfiniteParadax Class [Here](https://github.com/jasonmarziani/CCParallaxScrollNode), to repeat same backgrounds all time.
- [Slider code](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/9803) [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvQOnk4RgmM) the video.
- Split screen using 2 layers [Here](http://blog.bigbunkerstudio.com/?p=154)
- Sharped Label TTF, [Better labels](https://rombosblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/prevent-blurry-fonts-when-using-cclabelttf/)

**ADVANCED**

- Integrating OpenFeint with cocos2d-x. I only found [This example](http://blog.molioapp.com/2011/11/openfeint-and-admob-integrated-with.html), [Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/10/topics/9191) more details.
- Archievement on GameCenter. [Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/6891)

**Extensions**

- I have not tested all, but work fine [walzer's Extensions](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-extensions)
- [MarkusPfundstein](https://github.com/MarkusPfundstein/Cocos2DX-Extensions)'s extensions
- DualFace [extensions](https://github.com/dualface/cocos2d-x-extensions), actually in development

**Code Examples**

- *Clawoo examples*
- [Simple Game 1](https://github.com/clawoo/SimpleGameCocos2D-x)
- [Simple Game 1 - part 2](https://github.com/clawoo/SimpleGamePart2Cocos2D-x)
- [Simple Game 1 - part 3](https://github.com/clawoo/SimpleGamePart3Cocos2D-x)
- [BreakOut](https://github.com/clawoo/BreakoutCocos2D-x)
- [Pong](https://github.com/clawoo/PongCocos2D-x)
- [Cute a pult](https://github.com/clawoo/CuteAPultCocos2D-x)
- [TileBased game](https://github.com/clawoo/TileBasedGameCocos2D-x)
- [Asteroids](https://github.com/clawoo/AsteroidsCocos2D-x)
- *Bada.com*
- [Ballon Ride](http://developer.bada.com/library/BalloonRide)
- *Demo and links collection*
- [supersuraccoon-cocos2d demos (Not all C++)](http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2011/09/17/sticky-demo-resource-list-keep-updating/)
- [supersuraccoon-cocos2d links collection](http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2012/02/11/sticky-ios-cocos2d-develop-recommended-blog-list-keep-updating/)
- Another code example: [Tiny Wings Remake on Android using Cocos2d-X](https://github.com/diwu/Tiny-Wings-Remake-on-Android)

**TIPS**

- Audio format [Supported](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Audio_formats_supported_by_CocosDenshion_on_different_platforms)
- If you use Linux, please, don't use cocos2d-android or cocos2d-android-1, **is decreated**. Try to use cocos2d-x
- If you use Linux, and don't know how to use native code, [Take a look in development](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)
- CCLOG("String"); Don't work on Eclipse log cat, but CCLog do it!
- Max textures size/resolution [Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Max_size_of_textures_in_cocos2d-x_depends_on_each_platform)
- Iphone use RETINA to draw textures in HD, but don't are used on Android. My solution is use RETINA on iphone, and setscale compiling only in Android. [Multi-resolution Wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_does_cocos2d-x_support_multi-resolution). In Example:

```
    #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    this->setObjectScale(1);
    #endif  // CC_PLATFORM_IOS
```

- Your first example must be the official on the [WIKI](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki)

** [OFFICIAL PAGE COCOS2D-X](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) **

What will need this question?

- XML Tutorial, i have nothing in this area. Actually, i'm working in some code. I will do a Tutorial. The library can be use is [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)
- Creating menus example
- Slider menu example
- Gestures class don´t implemented yet

If you have problems, use tag Cocos2d-x in Stackoverflow, and I will try to help you.

I have already read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) but 90 % of questions cocos2d/android related present the same problem, using obsolete libraries. I just want help people to start using cocos2d-x. All additional info will be Welcome.

Comment: @jptsetung, i´m looking for the completest guide to use cocos2d-x, because is very difficult to start using it without help. So, i´m looking people to answer this question. Take a look here -> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: You should make this question community wiki, so that we can add this in FAQ.

Comment: I need to know how to read xml files. is the any tutorial yet?

Comment: Cocos2d-x is going to change the library to read XML, im waiting to prepare 1 tutorial

Comment: @Piperoman: have you seen the [Paralaxer Cocos2d-X](http://paralaxer.com) example game project?

Comment: Yes, it was released 1 month ago. But is too expensive to buy source :D

Comment: @Fugogugo: Cocos2d-X does have built-in XML support to read files on the Android platform and parse property lists. However, it's not something they've simplified, exported, or made available to use in your game's code. I highly recommend using [TinyXML2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html) to read your XML files.

Comment: Meta question about this question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155531/question-is-very-popular-but-closednot-constructive-shouldnt-it-be-reopened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you got complementaries discussions about the topic, it can be interesting.

[discussion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483877/cocos2d-x-vs-cocos2d-android-for-an-android-game)

[discussion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399341/cocos2d-for-iphone-vs-cocos2d-x)

Comment: Recommended :http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Answer (score 8):

Another code example: [Tiny Wings Remake on Android using Cocos2d-X](https://github.com/diwu/Tiny-Wings-Remake-on-Android)

Answer (score 6):

Good list. The [Angry Ninjas Starter Kit](http://www.cartoonsmart.com/angry_ninjas_starterkit.php5) will have a Cocos2d-X update soon.

Answer (score 6):

Cocos2d-x within uikit tutorial http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/24983791554/mixing-cocos2d-x-uikit

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/dualface/cocos2d-x-extensions/blob/master/TODO.tasks
, he is developing nice features on cocos2d-x

Answer (score 5):

Cocos2d-x within your classic Android (Java) app tuto http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/26000816688/integrate-cocos2d-x-c-into-an-android-application