# Work with xml in cocos2d-x

Tags: xml, svg, xml-parsing, cocos2d-x

I have a SVG file, which is in the assets folder. How can I gain access and parsing it so that I could retrieve data about path, and as in future write new path? There are internal tools for working with xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to the test projects, in [cocos2d-2.0-rc0a-x-2.](http://cocos2d-x.googlecode.com/files/cocos2d-2.0-rc0a-x-2.0.zip)0/tests running the Android.mk and launching the apk with eclipse (In linux). There are an examples to manage xml. The test is: UserDefaultTest. Don´t need to know anything. If XML don´t exist, the values return -1. If need more help just post a concrete question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But now there is a problem with running tests :) Making games in Kubuntu using cocos2d-x is not the simplest thing. By the way, how important and how well the need to work with NDK?

Comment: you NEED to work with NDK, because all code is in c++, so you need use JNI (Java native interface), take a look to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364