# Cocos2d-Android Custom font not working

Tags: cocos2d-android, custom-font

I am trying to use custom font in Cocos2d-Android with CClabel, I have added my font file into the assets and trying to use it by name "Faraco_Hand.ttf" and "Faraco_Hand" but its not working, I have googled around but haven't found any solution. this is how my code looks a like:

```
currentVideoLabel = CCLabel.makeLabel(VideosLabels[currentSelected], "Faraco_Hand.ttf", winSize.width/41);
        currentVideoLabel.setPosition(CGPoint.make(winSize.width/2, 20));
        addChild(currentVideoLabel);
```

If someone know this please help me.

Comment: Cocos2d-android don´t have support anymore. You must use cocos2d-x, cross-plataform, use JNI to use c++ code. More info [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364). The problem you are asking is solve in a test inside cocos2d-x, take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i use this way to add font in my game here i am sharing you my code check it hope it's  helpful for you here i am setting my font on label this is the only way to set fonts...all the best

Example:1

```
 CCLabel labelcontinue = CCLabel.makeLabel("continue", "fonts/JimboStd-Black.otf", 14);
                labelcontinue.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(272, 95));
                labelcontinue.setColor(ccColor3B.ccc3(165, 42, 42));
                mainPaperNode.addChild(labelcontinue, 25);
```

Example2:

```
  CCLabel labelWelcome = CCLabel.makeLabel("Welcome", "fonts/JimboStdBlack.otf",20);
        labelWelcome.setColor(ccColor3B.ccc3(139, 69, 19));
        labelWelcome.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(innerArea.getContentSize().getWidth() / 2, (innerArea.getContentSize().getHeight() / 2) + 138));
        innerArea.addChild(labelWelcome);
```

Comment: Why what is the problem....?facing any error during using this code..? i am using this in my game and its working fine..

Comment: Priyank.. no its not making any change in my font. I want to use comic sans font.

Comment: You have to use .otf file for using font like this way is is Comicsans.otf format..?then it should work

Comment: I was using .ttf but now i have tried with comic.otf. but  still if doesn't make change.I have converted .ttf to .otf

Comment: see this link. i need the help from cocos2d-android persons : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971120/can-we-use-googleads-admob-adwhirl-in-cocos2d-android

Comment: OTF fonts are not supported in Android, you can only use TTF fonts.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is late reply, anyhow it may help someone who search this same thing...
CCLabel supports external fonts but some of the ttf will not recognized by android so it will through exception so better you try another font instead of this the code is same...

```
  label = CCLabel.makeLabel("label value", "external_font_name.ttf", 30);
  label.setPosition(CGPoint.make(winSize.width/2, 20));
  addChild(label);
```

Comment: see this link. i need the help from cocos2d-android persons : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971120/can-we-use-googleads-admob-adwhirl-in-cocos2d-android

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any problem with your method. I guess the problem is you are renaming the original font file. Rename the font file name with its original name (written in the font file itself, check attached image).

[image]

in this case, I kept my ttf file in **Resources/fonts** folder and wrote my code like:

```
CCLabelTTF* label = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello World", "fonts/A Damn Mess.ttf", 20);
```

Also check **CCLabelTTF** instead of **CCLabel**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: see this link. i need the help from cocos2d-android persons : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971120/can-we-use-googleads-admob-adwhirl-in-cocos2d-android

Answer (score 0):

*Hai this will help. This code works for me fine. Put custom font int assets->fonts*

```
CCLabel label1 = CCLabel.makeLabel("Points: 0", "fonts/pin.ttf", 28);
    label1.setColor(ccColor3B.ccWHITE);
    label1.setPosition(280f * scaleX, 550f * scaleY);
    addChild(label1);
```