# Android - admob + cocos2d

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-android

I would like to know, how can I add a admob banner in cocos2d view?

This is my class

```
public class TitleScreen extends CCLayer{

private ScreenBackground background;
private ScreenBackground background2;

/**
 * Intância do Player
 */
private MakeEnemyAnimation enemy;
private CCLayer enemyLayer;

public CCScene scene(){
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(this);
    return scene;
}

public TitleScreen(Context context){
    this.background = new ScreenBackground(Assets.BACKGROUND);
    this.background.setPosition(
            screenResolution(CGPoint.ccp(
                    screenWidth() / 2.0f,
                    screenHeight() / 2.0f
            )));

    this.addChild(this.background);

    this.enemyLayer = CCLayer.node();
    this.enemy = new MakeEnemyAnimation();
    this.enemyLayer.addChild(this.enemy);
    this.addChild(this.enemyLayer);

    CCSprite title = CCSprite.sprite(Assets.GAMETITLE);
    title.setPosition(screenResolution(
            CGPoint.ccp( screenWidth() / 2 , screenHeight() - 70)));
    title.setScaleX((float) 0.85);
    title.setScaleY((float) 0.9);

    this.addChild(title);

    MenuButtons menuLayer = new MenuButtons(context);
    this.addChild(menuLayer);

}
}
```

And that is the admob code

```
LinearLayout layout  = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    AdView adView = new AdView(context);

    adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    layout.addView(adView);
```

I'm already trying to do this over a week. I've tried many different ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this ***[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971120/can-we-use-googleads-admob-adwhirl-in-cocos2d-android)*** : put in onstart method.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),                        
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()+getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-50);

adView = new AdView(SimpleGame.this, AdSize.BANNER, "your Ad ID");
adView.setAdListener(SimpleGame.this);                            
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(request);                

CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().addContentView(adView,adParams);
```