# Collision is not working properly in Box2D with Cocos2d Android

Tags: android, box2d, cocos2d-android

The `beginContact` callback function is being called for the bodies that are not colliding.

I have many bodies on the screen, all are far away from each other, but suddenly collision occurs and contact listener starts returning all the bodies on the screen but they are not actually colliding.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I recomend you to change libraries to cocos2d-x, because cocos2d for android won't be updated anymore.

Cocos2d-x works in C++, and uses JNI (Java native interface) to work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364) is all the info you will need to start using it.

Comment: oops... I have almost developed the whole game. It will be difficult to change the engine now.