# Is possible to create a singleton c++ to authenticate and post in the wall using HTTP request to Facebook API?

Tags: c++, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-x

I'm working on linux.

I have been looking for a method to post on Facebook from a c++ app (that runs in Android and Iphone using cocos2d-x). I have found some code in c++ to post on Facebook and Twitter, but it does not compile on linux. [This](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/) or [this](http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/facebookdemo).

In theory, I think, using http request, it could be easy to do, but i'm not sure.

The same question on [cocosd2-x forum](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12492).

Some idea about this theory?

Is possible, but better use oficial libraries, added in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364) wiki

Comment: You should be aware that Facebook officially supports only PHP, and that their API changes often enough that you probably want a third-party platform which is popular enough to be reliably supported and/or simple enough that you can fix it. Are you already using Qt for other networking operations?

Comment: I'm not using Qt, the facebook-cpp-graph-api work using qt, but I use cocos2d-x libraries

Comment: if you are familiar with low level codes, you can try to use libcurl to send http request. libcurl is included in cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using curl. Here you are a LINK1 to compile it on cocos2d-x library, and a EXAMPLE2 using cocos2d-x.

LINK1: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_compile_libcurl

EXAMPLE2: http://www.jesusbosch.com/2012/08/internet-communications-with-cocos2d-x.html