# Android cocos2d

Tags: java, android

i am new to android cocos2d,i have created a game using player1 and player2 CCSprites n later in order to move player1  and player2 to sprite positions,its become complicated.please provide me required docment or solution.

Comment: [cocos2d document](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Reference),[cocos2d tutorial stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use move to actions for moving sprite and then run that actions on your player

```
    CCMoveTo moveTo = CCMoveTo.action(0.5f, CGPoint.ccp(x, y));
    mPlayer1.runAction(moveTo);
```

where x and y are the points where you want to move your sprite and 0.ff is time interval to complete that Action.