# getting started with cocos2d for android

Tags: android, game-engine, cocos2d-android

Do you know of some tutorials that would help get me started with cocos2d for android? I looked around but I couldn't find any the reason i would like it to be the android version is because I am much better programming in java then C++. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would use `Cocos2d-x`, because cocos2d doesn't have support anymore. `Cocos2d-x` is based on `C++` and use JNI to run on `Android`. You don't have to know how does it work, just compile it and program your game in C++. To start using it check: [The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364) and the official web of the project: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

Answer (score 2):

It is better to see the cocos2d project [org.cocos2d.tests package](https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/tree/master/cocos2d-android/src/org/cocos2d/tests). It will contain the examples of cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

For many developers (like me) who do not have "extensive" programming experience with C/C++ , and do not have enough time or willingness to learn, the Cocos2D for Android port written in Java is a really great option. 
Yes, it may not be as updated (bells and whistles) as the Cocos2d-x project, but it definitely has enough mirrored features to get you started.
Here is the github link to the most updated repository I know of 
https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d

And heres a brief set of tutorials to get you started ..

Step by Step Guide on How to build your first Slider Puzzle game in Cocos2d for Android – Part 1 
http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-build-your-first-slider-puzzle-game-in-cocos2d-for-android-part-1/

How To Make A Simple Android Game with Cocos2D
http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/

For all others coming to this thread, I hope this is useful!