# How to create a visable rectangle with no image in Cocos2D-Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

Can someone give me a simple example since I'm trying to learn it but haven't seen examples for Android, for iOS plenty though. I want to create one so it is easier to debug my collision area's. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don´t know it this helps you. I use Cocos2d-x. This library is the same that cocos2d-android, but:

- Works in C++, it is faster than Java
- Is multiplatform, can compile in iOS and Android, and HTML5
- Exist a big community whose hold the project, and cocos2d-android doesn´t have more updates

Exist [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list) link with a lof of tutoriales to start.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely take a look at it, I also noticed the community isn't big for cocos2d-android.