# What exactly do i need to learn to be able to use cocos2d & cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

In case it makes any difference i am learning c++ for cocos2d-x

I know what is meant by these STL, OOP & encapsulation.

I good with looping & I am ok with functions.

I am still working on classes i know what are the methods and member values but do i need know how to make complicated ones or will i need to use em only?

I will start on pointers anyway but i want to know will i need to use it?

Do i need to learn all of java to make the android part?

I just want to know if there is something i need to concentrate on because I am teaching myself and i want to as ready as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The best advice I can give you is to just start programming for cocos2d or 2d-x whatever you want to use. You won't learn it until you actually start using it.

That said,

> I am still working on classes i know what are the methods and member values but do i need know how to make complicated ones or will i need to use em only?

If your question is, if you should learn how to make your own objects, yes you definitely should. Object oriented programming is all about that.

> I will start on pointers anyway but i want to know will i need to use it?

Yes you will need to use them. The *s you see in the codes are pointers. I am 100% sure you can not create a game without them.

> Do i need to learn all of java to make the android part?

No, you do not need to learn "all" of Java. If you are using cocos2d-x you write your code in c++, however you will need to know how android applications are created in terms of creating your project and organizing your folders so that it can be built properly.

It seems that overall, you are just starting to learn programming, and that is great. When I started I didn't know what to start with, but from my personal experience it is just best to start making something. Yes, all the concepts and fundamentals are important, but it won't really stick to you until you actually use them and start figuring out how things work.

Finally if you are interested in cocos2d-x

[The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list)

try checking out some stuff from the above link.

For cocos2d tutorials Ray Wenderlich provides great tutorials.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/

I don't know what exactly you are interested in... if its creating apps, I suggest you start with normal apps on iPhone without Cocos2d, but if you really just want to make games, I suggest you start off with cocos2d not cocos2d-x. I haven't used cocos2d-x in a while now, but it has quite a few bugs and glitches... hopefully its better now. On the other hand Cocos2d is generally very stable and easy to use.

Good Luck!