# How to use .so and .h files in Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am using C++ to code in Android (I am using cocos2d-x, specifically).

Now, say, I have a class, `MyClass`, with .h and .cpp files. I would like to create a .so out of these files. Then, I would like to include that .so in my project and access it via `#include "MyClass.h"`. Is it possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list

Answer (score 1):

To build your static library for ARM you can use the [NDK standalone toolchain](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html).

Once you've compiled your `.so`, you can include the library in your project using the [Android NDK make file](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) (Android.mk) which will look like the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my_module.so  
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You'll want to make sure you include the headers (/include) in the right path.

Not sure if your intent is to ge back into Android-land with your code, but if you're looking to create a bridge between your .so/C/C++ code and Java, you'll need to describe the appropriate JNI methods in C, build out the necessary Java classes with the static `System.loadLibrary('my_module')` imports and `native` method declarations mapped to your JNI methods.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. Using the NDK standalone toolchain is very complicated. Is there a way to build the static library using the ndk-build? If so, how?

Comment: And btw, I am not going to code java to access the .so, just C++.