# Visual effects libraries for android game

Tags: android, visual-effects

I am developing a game, which needs few `visual effects (Bomb explosion , and so on)`, And of course they should look pretty and appealing. :) I searched a bit, but could't find any libraries.

So, I don't know i am headed in the right direction or not. Is there anything like a paid or free third party libraries which i can use.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Such libraries are ofter part of some game engine. For example libGDX has build-in particles system with an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1. [AndEngine](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) --> [github](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine).
2. Cocos2d-x --> [The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list) --> [github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x).
3. libGDX (as @Denis 'GeneralGDA' Gladkiy mentioned).

Comment: this helped ..http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/13/game-engines-for-android

Comment: Nice list, it will help me too :) Thanks for sharing.